# How to keep parts of the text you replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I would like to replace all new lines after lower cases with space.
Regex: "[a-z]\n" and only replace the \n with space.
How do I keep the lower case, when I replace it?

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/San2jj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Capture groups.

For your example, it would look like this:

Replace `([a-z])\n` with `$1`

$n represents the content of the nth capture group. Capture groups are created by putting braces ( ) arround a part of the regex.

Windows uses \r\n for newlines, so for here is a regex that supports both styles of line endings by making the \r optional:
`([a-z])\r?\n`